# Mysql query not running with or condition

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$query  = $_GET['search'];
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'discussion' AND post_status = 'publish' AND (post_content like '%".$query."%' OR post_title like '%".$query."%))");
```

In this query `OR` Condition is not running.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a single quote in this place `"%))");`. So the working code will be:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'discussion' AND post_status = 'publish' AND (post_content like '%".$query."%' OR post_title like '%".$query."%'))");
```

The `post_title like` having a starting `'` but doesn't have the closing `'`

Comment: @ManishSuthar: Is really the combination have valid data in the table?

Comment: Yes. I have two column in table post_title and post_content, When i remove or condition query perfectly running.

Comment: @ManishSuthar: Can you post some sample data, and value of `$query` in the question, it helps others to answer too.

Answer (score 0):

SQL command looks correct.
If $query is really not empty you can try this (sometimes helps if you define returned type):

```
$sql = 'your select';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
foreach ($results as $res) { ... }
```